# Open source / trusted rooting app for Android / Motorola Defy?

Tags: security, rooting, motorola-defy

I found a lot of compiled rooting exploits for Android, but not a lot of source code.

So, how can I trust an exploit able to take SU rights on my mobile device? How can I be sure there is no root-kit/bot/spyware inside?

I'm maybe a little paranoid, but this is a very serious issue for me:

My PDA contain a lot of private/secret informations (personal and professional), so, is there a trusted/secure way to root an Android device? (A Motorola Defy in particular)

---

[EDIT]

I insist on this last point:

> is there a trusted/secure way to root an Android device? (A Motorola Defy in particular)

Does anybody know an open source or trusted rooting app for Android, and Motorola Defy in particular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code for the adb exploit used in the superoneclickroot tool is available:
http://stealth.openwall.net/xSports/RageAgainstTheCage.tgz.

You would have to crosscompile RageAgainstTheCage.c (after reviewing it of course...) for arm5 and then do the whole adb thing, descibed for example here in thread no. 844966 at xda-dev (my one link was already used up, sorry).

I do *not* speak from experience however.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps a simple answer but if the author doesn't provide the sourcecode of the App und you know that it doesn't originate of a trusted source, you can't be sure that it's clean.

If it's a high risk for you you probably should not use it.

Comment: There are many devs who at least explain their methods though, so hopefully one could develop rooting software oneself from that.